# PHP DOMXPath query using the innerHTML/nodeValue of an element to find and return the element

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

Can you please help me with the correct syntax to use when you want to check the innerHTML/nodeValue of an element?

I have no problem with the Name however the Age is within a plain div element, What is the correct syntax to use in place of "NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE" below.

$html is a page from the internet

The persons name is in a span like:

```
<span class="fullname">John Smith</span>
```

The persons age is in a div like:

```
<div>Age: 28</div>
```

I have the following PHP:

```
<?php
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);

//Full Name
$findName = "fullname";
$queryName = $finder->query("//span[contains(@class, '$findName')]");
$name = $queryName->item(0)->nodeValue;

//Age
$findAge = "Age: ";
$queryAge = $finder->query("//div[NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE]");
$age = substr($queryAge->item(0)->nodeValue, 5);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$queryAge = $finder->query("//div[starts-with(., '$findAge')]");
```

I've had limited success with `starts-with()` due to whitespace so you may have to resort to

```
$queryAge = $finder->query("//div[contains(., '$findAge')]");
```

If there's a chance of finding false positives (ie, other divs with "Age: " in them), you might be able to avoid that by using a more specific path (if known), ie

```
$queryAge = $finder->query("//div[@id='something']//div[contains(., '$findAge')]");
```

Comment: This works thank you! can I ask where you got the information from? I can't find anything on the internet for the syntax to use for the DOMXPath contains method.

Comment: @Craig The official [XPath docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), specifically [`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains)